# Cannot get Method from assembly at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection, runtime, .net-assembly

I'm using the following code to load an assembly at runtime and then get a reference to a specific method and obviously execute it at the end:

```
var assemblyLoaded = Assembly.LoadFile(absolutePath);
var type = assemblyLoaded.GetType("CreateContactPlugin.Plugin");

var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

var methodInfo = type.GetMethod("Execute", new Type[] { typeof(System.String)});
if (methodInfo == null)
{
    throw new Exception("No such method exists.");
}
```

Here is the assembly that I'm calling

```
namespace CreateContactPlugin
{
   public class Plugin
   {

    static bool Execute(string contactName){
        bool contactCreated = false;
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contactName))
        {
            //process
        }
        return contactCreated;
    }

  }
 }
```

I can succesfully load the Assembly, the Type. When I highlight the **type** variable, I see the method listed in the DeclaredMethods array. But when I try to get the Method, it returns always null.

Does somebody see what I might be doing wrong here ?

Comment: Please use BindingFlags: type.GetMethod("Execute", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static). Without BindingFlags.Static you may not successfully get the "Execute" method. (note: the 'Execute' method isn't public)

Comment: As an aside, I wouldn't recommend doing it this way. It seems you're making a plugin system. Instead, make the plugin class implement a shared interface, then you can make the `instance` variable be a `IPluginThing` instead of an object. Now you can call `Execute` without using reflection. Oh, and don't make it a static method, no point in making an instance otherwise.

Comment: And... make the Execute method public too...

Comment: And move *var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);* as the last line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Reflection to get static method with its parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117372/using-reflection-to-get-static-method-with-its-parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of problems here. First of all the `Execute` method is `static` and not `public` so you need to specify the correct binding flags to get at it.

```
var methodInfo = type.GetMethod("Execute", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

However, an alternative (and preferable in my opinion) solution using less reflection and strong typing would be to make your plugin class implement a common interface, that way you can strongly type your `instance` object. First make a class library with the relevant interfaces in it, for example:

```
public interface IContactPlugin
{
    bool Execute(string contactName);
}
```

Now your plugin can also reference the same library and becomes this:

```
namespace CreateContactPlugin
{
    public class Plugin : IContactPlugin
    {
        public bool Execute(string contactName)
        {
            //snip
        }
    }
}
```

And your calling code would now be this:

```
var assemblyLoaded = Assembly.LoadFile(absolutePath);
var type = assemblyLoaded.GetType("CreateContactPlugin.Plugin");

var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IContactPlugin;

if (instance == null)
{
    //That type wasn't an IContactPlugin, do something here...
}

instance.Execute("name of contact");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is "static" of

```
static bool Execute(string contactName)
```

put it as

```
public bool Execute(string contactName)
```